# Kendo js jpg to pdf issue

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, export, export-to-pdf

Ohaiyo,
i have been trying to export pdf file from html using kendo ui, js and c# asp.net.
It exports the file but is missing jpg pictures specifically on top of that it isn't making any issue with png file . Kindly guide me accordingly.
My code,

```
    function ExportToPDF(printdiv) {

        onUpdating();

        var grid = $("#chart_div");
        kendo.drawing.drawDOM(grid).then(function (group) {
            kendo.drawing.pdf.saveAs(group, "OrgChart.pdf");
            setTimeout(function () {
                onUpdated();
            }, 1000);
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the limitations and browser support for the Kendo drawing library here:

https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/drawing/limitations-browser-support

Specifically, for images it lists:

- Only the export of images with correct extensions is supported. For example, a PNG image with a JPG extension that is displayed on a page might not show up in the exported PDF file or might cause exceptions in the PDF reader.
- Images without permissive Cross-Origin HTTP headers will not be rendered.
- Internet Explorer 9 is not be able to load images or fonts from another domain, and could raise an uncatchable security exception. If you need to support Internet Explorer 9, make sure to host images and fonts on the same domain as the application.
- Images will not be exported in IE if their source is an SVG document. These are considered to be tainted.

Comment: Koni,chiwa, sir the thing is that freshly downloaded jpg images are uploaded that clears the false extension issue but still png images are successfully exported to pdf where as it isn't exporting jpg images and also i am using chrome